# Rails query/scope: exclude objects according to attribute of joined model

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My models look like this:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tickets
end
```

I want to have a scope that gives me all of the distinct `Tickets` that are not tagged `unresolved` (as in `tag.name != "unresolved"`)

How would I go about doing this? For example, if 1 ticket has 6 tags (one of which being `unresolved`) I only want to return 1 instance of that ticket, not 5 in the scope. I've managed to do the opposite (all `Tickets` that *are* tagged `unresolved`) as such:

```
scope :unresolved, :select => "DISTINCT tickets.*", :joins => :tags, :conditions => "tags.name = 'unresolved'"
```

Comment: Is the double == in your condition a typo?

Comment: @iWasRobbed: So if I had one Ticket with 6 Tags it would appear in the join table 6 times. If I didn't have the `DISTINCT` clause, that call would return 5 Tickets... every "entry" in the tags_ticket table that wasn't linked to a tag with name `"unresolved"`

Comment: @iWasRobbed: Re-read my scenario for the subtle difference. I have **one** Ticket in the database with 6 Tags. If I made the call as you suggested without `DISTINCT` and with `:conditions => "tags.name != 'unresolved'"` I will get the **same** Ticket back 5 times--once for every appearance in the join table not linked to the `unresolved` tag.

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible without writing a very complex custom SQL query. Tags probably aren't the best hammer for this nail. It would probably be more appropriate to just add a boolean 'resolved' field to the Ticket model and flip it on or off as necessary. It would certainly be easier to query.

Comment: @JonGarvin You're probably right, going with the boolean field is likely my best bet

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how flexible you want the scope to chain you have two options.

1. Use `uniq` within the scope (note: this may have a negative impact on chaining this scope with others, especially when adding more complex conditionals):

   `scope :unresolved, -> { joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: 'unresolved' }).uniq }`
2. Use a LEFT OUTER join via `includes(:tags)` instead of the INNER join default used by `joins(:tags)`

   `scope :unresolved, -> { includes(:tags).where(tags: { name: 'unresolved' }) }`